# code for calculations in android

Tags: java, android

I'm working with an application right now for our project in school. My application is about Resistor Color Code calculation. My codes are working, but in displaying the values, I used the value as string. My problem is I want to make my result value as 1.2K ohms, 1.5M ohm or 5.4M ohms, just like that. Because in my codes the result will display 1200 ohms, 1500K ohms or 5400K ohms. Help me Please. Thanks in advance for the help.

This is my code for a, b, c, d and value is the display in `EditText`.

calcu is a button.

```
calcu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //for first band
            if (a=="Black")
                a = " ";
            if (a=="Brown")
                a = "1";
            if (a=="Red")
                a = "2";
            if (a=="Orange")
                a = "3";
            if (a=="Yellow")
                a = "4";
            if (a=="Green")
                a = "5";
            if (a=="Blue")
                a = "6";
            if (a=="Violet")
                a = "7";
            if (a=="Gray")
                a = "8";
            if (a=="White")
                a = "9";
            //for second band
            if (b=="Black")
                b = "0";
            if (b=="Brown")
                b = "1";
            if (b=="Red")
                b = "2";
            if (b=="Orange")
                b = "3";
            if (b=="Yellow")
                b = "4";
            if (b=="Green")
                b = "5";
            if (b=="Blue")
                b = "6";
            if (b=="Violet")
                b = "7";
            if (b=="Gray")
                b = "8";
            if (b=="White")
                b = "9";
            //for multiplier
            if (c=="Black")
                c = " ";
            if (c=="Brown")
                c = "0";
            if (c=="Red")
                c = "00";
            if (c=="Orange")
                c = "000";
            if (c=="Yellow")
                c = "0000";
            if (c=="Green")
                c = "00000";
            if (c=="Blue")
                c = "000000";
            if (c=="Violet")
                c = "0000000";
            if (c=="Gray")
                c = "00000000";
            if (c=="White")
                c = "000000000";            
            //for Tolerance

            if (d=="Brown")
                d = "1";
            if (d=="Red")
                d = "2";        
            if (d=="Green")
                d = "0.5";
            if (d=="Blue")
                d = "0.25";
            if (d=="Violet")
                d = "0.1";
            if (d=="Gray")
                d = "0.05";
            if (d=="Gold")
                d = "5";
            if (d=="Silver")
                d = "10";

Value.setText(a + b + c + "\u2126" + " " + "\u00B1" + d + "%" + " Tolerance");
```

Comment: So you're displaying strings that say "1200 ohms" and "5400K ohms", but you want "1.2K ohms" and "5.4M ohms"?

Comment: yup! but I set all the numbers as strings.

Comment: I see `Value.setText(a + b + c + "\u2126" + " " + "\u00B1" + d + "%" + " Tolerance");` in your comment to End.Fouad. Can you post a little more code to show what `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are? (Are the strings, ints, etc?)

Comment: Also, you should be using `.equals()` for your String comparisons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int result = getTheResult();
String Result = "";
if(result > 0 && result < 1000) Result = "" + result + " Ohms";
else if(result >= 1000 && result < 1000000) Result = "" + (result / 1000) + "K Ohms";
else if (result >= 1000000) Result = "" + (result / 1000000) + "M Ohms";
else Result = "Invalid Value";
```

Comment: Thanks for this man. It has an error in the "getTheResult". I display the value in an editText and my code is this. Value.setText(a + b + c + "\u2126" + " " + "\u00B1" + d + "%" + " Tolerance"); where a is for the first band, b is for the 2nd and c for the multiplier but a,b,c are all strings. in c I just put "K" for orange or "0 K" for yellow, just like that.. :(

Comment: It is name for your method that performs calculation.

Comment: I've tried this but when I choose Brown,Red,Red it will display 1Kohms only.. this is what I did. String e = a + b + c;
            int ken = Integer.parseInt(e);
            
             int result = ken;
             String Result = "";
             if(result > 0 && result < 1000) Result = "" + result + " Ohms";
             else if(result >= 1000 && result < 1000000) Result = "" + (result / 1000) + "K Ohms";
             else if (result >= 1000000) Result = "" + (result / 1000000) + "M Ohms";
             else Result = "Invalid Value";

Comment: Thanks for this! I Finally got it. I used Double instead of integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Resistance {

String digit_band1_color;
String digit_band2_color;
String multiplier_band3_color;
String tolerance_band4_color;
int temp1,temp2,temp3;
double temp4;
double result;

public Resistance(String a,String b,String c,String d){
    digit_band1_color=a;
    digit_band2_color=b;
    multiplier_band3_color=c;
    tolerance_band4_color=d;
    switch (digit_band1_color){
        case "Black":
            temp1=0;
            break;
        case "Brown":
            temp1=1;
            break;
        case "Red":
            temp1=2;
            break;
        case "Orange":
            temp1=3;
            break; 
        case "Yellow":
            temp1=4;
            break; 
        case "Green":
            temp1=5;
            break;
        case "Blue":
            temp1=6;
            break; 
        case "Voilet":
            temp1=7;
            break;
        case "Grey":
            temp1=8;
            break;
        case "White":
            temp1=9;
            break;    
    }

     switch (digit_band2_color){
        case "Black":
            temp2=0;
            break;
        case "Brown":
            temp2=1;
            break;
        case "Red":
            temp2=2;
            break;
        case "Orange":
            temp2=3;
            break; 
        case "Yellow":
            temp2=4;
            break; 
        case "Green":
            temp2=5;
            break;
        case "Blue":
            temp2=6;
            break; 
        case "Voilet":
            temp2=7;
            break;
        case "Grey":
            temp2=8;
            break;
        case "White":
            temp2=9;
            break;    
    }

      switch (multiplier_band3_color){
        case "Black":
            temp3=0;
            break;
        case "Brown":
            temp3=1;
            break;
        case "Red":
            temp3=2;
            break;
        case "Orange":
            temp3=3;
            break; 
        case "Yellow":
            temp3=4;
            break; 
        case "Green":
            temp3=5;
            break;
        case "Blue":
            temp3=6;
            break; 
        case "Voilet":
            temp3=7;
            break;
        case "Grey":
            temp3=8;
            break;
        case "White":
            temp3=9;
            break;    
    }

      switch (tolerance_band4_color){
        case "Brown":
            temp4=1;
            break;
        case "Red":
            temp3=2;
            break;
        case "Orange":
            temp4=0.05;
            break; 
        case "Yellow":
            temp4=0.02;
            break; 
        case "Green":
            temp4=0.5;
            break;
        case "Blue":
            temp4=0.25;
            break; 
        case "Voilet":
            temp4=0.1;
            break;
        case "Grey":
            temp4=0.01;
            break;
        case "Gold":
            temp4=5;
            break; 
        case "Silver":
            temp4=10;
            break;    
    }

    result=Math.pow(10,temp3);
    System.out.println("Resistance = "+temp1+temp2+result+"+-"+temp4+"%");     
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Enter Color in Proper Format like this Black,Brown etc");
    String b=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Enter Color in Proper Format like this Black,Brown etc");
    String c=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Enter Color in Proper Format like this Black,Brown etc");
    String d=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Enter Color in Proper Format like this Black,Brown etc");
    Resistance calculator=new Resistance(a,b,c,d);
}
    
}
```